# Difficulty with word problem interpretation

Tags: secondary-education, word-problems

I've tutored math SAT prep for some years now, and have developed a routine with certain texts and exercises that I have found to be fairly successful in improving scores overall. I recognize that many students face a challenge in translating word problems into algebraic expressions, and am usually able to make progress toward this problem with most of my students.

However I am currently tutoring a student for whom this issue presents a greater challenge than I've encountered. I say "greater challenge" because my metric is the disparity between his comprehension of and familiarity with the underlying algebra (which is fairly strong) and his ability to put word problems into algebraic terms (which is almost non-existent). I've looked online for instances of this disparity occurring at such a remarkable level, but have only found literature on the general difficulty faced by many children.

Does anyone have any experience with this sort of problem, and are there any techniques, exercises, methods of explanation, etc. that have exhibited notable success toward remedying such an issue?

Comment: I'm just curious:  are the word problems in the same language as the first language of the student?

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche They are.

Comment: I'm intrigued. This sounds like a case study waiting to be published (as done in medical circles).

Comment: Does the student exhibit a general difficulty in the area of written language, i.e. not limited to language about mathematics?

Comment: Have you started with simple English phrases to be translated to algebra? For example $3 more than the price.  4 miles less than the distance. Half as many people.  How does the student  do with those?

Comment: @shoover As far as I know, he does not.

Comment: @AmyB I did not start with anything that rudimentary. He is in high-school-level calculus, and I didn't think he would have been able to progress that far without understanding basic English-to-algebra translation. His problem is of a different sort. For example, if he is told that two real-world variables have a linear relationship and is then given two points of data, he has no idea how to interpret this. However, if you give him two points on a line, he is able to find the equation of that line.

Comment: I asked about rudimentary levels because there must be gaps somewhere along the way and you need to find out what they are.  He may be high school level calculus but some part of him is way below that.  Therefore you have to find out where the disconnect occurs.  Sometimes the way to do that is to find out what level he missed.  In your example,  does he know what a linear relationship is?  Can he translate that to they are on the same line? etc.

Comment: Agree with @AmyB: do a binary search from most rudimentary to calculus to try to find where the gap starts.

Comment: I've worked as a math teacher in a technical school (hotels and tourism), some students were not interested at all. At the age of 14, one of them was asking "But sir, why are you always working with letters instead of numbers?" as I worked with variables for generality reasons. I've explained it to her again, but she simply did not want to understand it: once the difficulty reached a certain level, the limit of her brain/ willingness to understand were reached, and I just bumped into a wall. Some students simply lack the ability to understand even simple things, whatever effort you spend.

Comment: I'm with AmyB.  You need to be more analytical about gap identification.  Even the question statement didn't really give info on examples of the gaps (had to probe for it).  And then your "I'm sure he is too advanced" answer shows a cognitive blind spot.  Be more scientific.  Do experiments and learn things.

Comment: Can you provide examples of what the student can and can't do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Recently, I got to teach a new high school class called "Essentials of College Math." It sounds like hard content, but it was basically just a transition course from Algebra II to Precal. Anyways, [this](http://www.sreb.org/sites/main/files/math_ready_teacher_guide_student_manual_v3.pdf) is the teacher's manual for the course (which also includes all the student handouts). The first unit was called "algebraic expressions" and dealt with this topic of translating words to equations quite a bit with some good activities, especially the card sorting activities. I found Task #5 ("the swimming pool") to be quite useful. In fact, I did a whole 2 or 3 days after that task just devoted to dot patterns (from [visualpatterns.org](http://www.visualpatterns.org/)) and having students create their own expressions for the patterns. We proved that two different expressions generated the same pattern. I would also give them a list of different solutions and ask them where they see the different aspects of the expression in the visual picture. (similar to this [task](https://www.illustrativemathematics.org/content-standards/tasks/21), I found Levi's comment on the task particularly insightful).

Comment: "Entry Event: Play initial clip of Bucky the Badger." - did you say it was a high school book?

Comment: Yes, this is a high school book. What is your question about Bucky the Badger? Did you have a look at the task?

Comment: I had not looked. I looked just now. This is a brutal progression. Just did not expect to watch videos in a high school math class, but if it works than hats off.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "a brutal progression," but the Bucky the Badger activity did work quite well when I used it my class. Anything that helps to get students arguing / debating / discussing mathematical ideas with each other is a success.

Answer (score 10):

I suggest you break it down into smaller parts. In fact, don't start on equations. Start on translation of terms:

- Double of a number, translation: $2x$
- Sum of two numbers, translation: $x+y$
- The triple of a number after adding five units, translation: $3(x+5)$

Next combine translations into equations:

- The double of a number is equal to the triple of another, translation: $2x = 3y$
- The sum of two numbers is equal to the triple of the first after adding five units, translation: $x+y = 3(x+5)$

Make sure you work through many standard terms before moving on.

A table may be helpful: one column for the word terms and another for the algebraic translation.

Treat each line of the table as one translation step as you read a word problem: start with "The double of a number...", and the second column reads $2x$; then continue with "...minus 30...", and the second column reads $2x-30$; complete with "...equals the number.", and the second column reads $2x-30=x$.

Sounds tiring, but worth the effort if your student understands and internalizes the process to the point of no longer needing such device.

Comment: I like this answer a lot; the goal would be a realization by the student that many statements in English can be translated into algebra.

Comment: I don't know about more recent texts, but it was fairly standard in older beginning algebra texts (before late 1950s, when new math entered the scene) to have an introductory section or two, sometimes an entire chapter, devoted to translations from verbal to mathematical (both expressions and equations). For example, the first 23 pages of [this book from my bookshelves](http://www.worldcat.org/title/algebra-meaning-and-mastery-book-one/oclc/798460481) deals with this, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to be freely available on the internet. But coming up with practice examples should be easy.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro: This is still common in algebra texts today. Each of the half-dozen or so recent algebra texts on my shelf does this. For example: *OpenStax Elementary Algebra*, Section 1.2, "Use the Language of Algebra": https://cnx.org/contents/CImQfPDv@2.44:faHRo7tY@3/Use-the-Language-of-Algebra

Comment: @Daniel R. Collins: The reason I used the cut-off of the late 1950s is that the very few more recent beginning algebra texts I have are from the 1960s to early 1970s, and translation exercises such as these are mostly absent in them. I don't have anything more recent at the beginning algebra level, so I was playing it safe by saying "I don't know about more recent texts".

Comment: I wonder how many students might think that "the triple of the first after adding 5 units" would be 3x + 5.  We are used to some very formalized ways of specifying things.  But most people aren't at all, and don't see much difference without a lot of experience.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure he really understands what kind of actions each of the basic operations serve as a model.

So before algebraization of problems, try to work on **identify the actions involved**. Next, **Singapur bar models** can be useful as an intermediate way of modelling what's happening, specially on the relevance they put un identifying the total involved.

Comment: Mind elaborating on what Singapur bar models is? I'm not familiar with it and so a reference would be great.

Comment: Here is a nice guide to it http://www.thedailyriff.com/WordProblems.pdf
But they're a model halway between pictorical and abstract representation of a situation, where you can have one or more bars, usually one of them representing some kind of total, and it's split according to the parts involved forming this total or comparison.

Comment: Do you mean *Singapore* bar models?